# Clickhouse - ARRAY JOIN very slow

Tags: sql, database, performance, relational-database, clickhouse

I am currently facing an issue with slow queries, mainly due to the large size of the `my_table_local` table The situation becomes even more unbearable when attempting to expand the data column using an ARRAY JOIN operation. Even a simple row count operation takes minutes:

```sql
SELECT count() FROM my_table_local ARRAY JOIN data
```

To address this, I attempted to create a similar table named `my_table_expanded_local` with expanded data, but surprisingly, queries on this table turned out to be even slower (2x slower). Upon analyzing the situation using the EXPLAIN command, it became evident that reading from the expanded table is slower than performing an ARRAY JOIN.

Expanding the table resulted in a row count approximately 30 times larger than the original.

My specific use case necessitates the use of generic queries. Therefore, options like Aggregated tables or materialized views are not feasible, unless they can seamlessly support generic queries.

The most frequent queries involve GROUP BY operations on various columns (excluding customerId), with flexibility in terms of column order and combinations.

Do you have any suggestions on how I can optimize the performance of ARRAY JOIN for my use case?

CREATE SQL for both tables

Original that requires ARRAY JOIN

```
CREATE TABLE default.my_table_local
(
    `customerId` String,
    `timestamp` DateTime,
    `userId` Nullable(String),
    `itemId` Nullable(String),
    `data` Array(String),
    INDEX userId_index userId TYPE bloom_filter(0.001) GRANULARITY 1,
    INDEX itemId_index itemId TYPE bloom_filter(0.001) GRANULARITY 1,
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY (customerId, toYYYYMM(timestamp))
ORDER BY (customerId, timestamp)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```

Expanded

```
CREATE TABLE default.my_table_expanded_local
(
    `customerId` String,
    `timestamp` DateTime,
    `userId` Nullable(String),
    `itemId` Nullable(String),
    `data` String,
    INDEX userId_index userId TYPE bloom_filter(0.001) GRANULARITY 1,
    INDEX itemId_index itemId TYPE bloom_filter(0.001) GRANULARITY 1,
)
ENGINE = MergeTree
PARTITION BY (customerId, toYYYYMM(timestamp))
ORDER BY (customerId, timestamp)
SETTINGS index_granularity = 8192
```